# Why doesnt my app connect to the Firestore database as it should?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I am creating a simple sign in with Firebase auth, and then the additonal details i need are then being stored in the firestore for convenience. I have ran a log of the lead up to and after the db connections and for whatever reason its just not having any of it. The listeners are giving me nothing and the log for after comes up asif its just skiped over that line.

**What i've tried**
I made a similar start to the app previously so my first port of call was that. Made the code identical and still no joy. (I tested the other app to make sure it works)

Then i took to google, made sure my Gradle(app&Project) had all the correct up to date implementations. Made sure everything was up to date.

Tried adding a collection manually to create the file path (I know it adds it for you if the directory isnt created but just thought it try)

After that failiure, i then proceeded back onto the document references and copy'd and pasted their generic libary code just to see what happends and nothing. So then i took it out of the function and tried it on a button press, Still no joy, So then i added it to the on create without a function.

Made sure the json file is up to date and replaced that. I then tried differed minimu SDK versions up to 22. No Joy

It still doesnt write to the database, the authenication works fine, however, i went onto the firebase portal and had a look at the stats and it would appear its reading the database then not doing anything. Its registered 57 reads, 1 write (the manual one i did to create the collection) 3 active connections, 6 snapshots peak.

As this didnt work, i then proceeded to create this as a new file, just incase it was one of the imports messing with it and still the same issue. I am about ready to screem. So please point out my obvious mistake becuase i cannot find it and its drivng me insane!! I appreciate everyones help and again, i do appologise if it has been covered before!

*Edit:* I did also give up with firestore and just tried to write to realime, but same issue again, it just skiped over it...

**The Function**

```
    private fun createUserInFirestore(uid:String) {
        var cUsername = te_username.text.toString()
        var cEmail = te_email.text.toString()
        //var cNumber = te_contact.text.toString()
//        var cBuissness = cb_buisness.isChecked
//        var cPersonal = cb_personal.isChecked
//        var cResult = ""
//        if (cBuissness) {
//            cResult = "Buisness"
//        } else if (cPersonal) {
//            cResult = "Personal"
//        }
//        var cHouse = te_house.text.toString()
//        var cPostCode = te_post_code.text.toString()
        val db = Firebase.firestore
        val user = hashMapOf(
            "uid" to uid,
            "username" to cUsername,
            "email" to cEmail
        )
        Log.d("TAG", "WE GOT THIS $user")
        // Add a new document with a generated ID
        db.collection("users")
            .add(user)
            .addOnSuccessListener { documentReference ->
                Log.d("TAG", "DocumentSnapshot added with ID: ${documentReference.id}")
            }
            .addOnFailureListener { e ->
                Log.w("TAG", "Error adding document", e)
            }


    }
```

**imports**

```
import android.content.Intent
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.widget.Toast
import com.example.APP.MainActivity
import com.example.APP.R
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase
import com.google.firebase.firestore.ktx.firestore
import com.google.firebase.ktx.Firebase
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_register.*
```

**GRADLE**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.APP"
        multiDexEnabled = true
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.3.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore-ktx:21.4.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    //implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: I have a feeling you're missing `implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:21.4.3'` in your dependencies.

Comment: I did have the ktx version. I replaced this without the KTX but still no joy :(

Comment: Have you added the firebase json of your project to your android asset files?

Comment: @Haroon yes i have, I also replaced it just incase it was currupt

Comment: Didn't you find the solution? I have the same issue.